# Python zip function - weird result

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Learning python, came across the zip function and understand that it should build pairs of 2 lists. However, it does not seem to work in my IDE.

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['p','q','r']
r = zip(a,b)
print(r)
```

Here I would expect a print of [('a','p'), ('b','q'), ('c','r')]. However, the print output then is: `<zip object at 0x011E57D8>`

Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `r = list(zip(a, b))`.

Comment: What does the documentation say that `zip` returns?  "*Returns an iterator of tuples*" - an iterator, not the tuples themselves.  Typical use of `zip` is in a `for` loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Python 3. In Python 3, `zip()` returns an iterator instead of a list.

Iterators evaluation is lazy: only one item is returned at a time, and there is no `__len__`. Iterators are made to work best for loop: indeed, most of the time `zip()` will be used in a loop, where you only need one item at a time, saving memory and CPU cycles.

Just try to do `list(zip(a,b))` to force the evaluation of the iterator into a list.

Comment: Also try `dict(zip(a,b))` and `[low+high for (low,high) in zip(a,b)]`

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 3. Because Python 3 is lazy (as compared to Python 2), collection functions like `zip` return a `zip` object instead of the result of the `zip`. Just print it using `print(list(r))`.

Comment: @Psidom On the whole Python 3 defaults to lazy evaluation where Python 2 would not.

Answer (score 1):

From [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

> **zip(*iterables)**
>
> Make an ***iterator*** that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

In Python, you use **for** loop to iterate over an object (list, dict, string, etc). On a lower level, the **for** loop is implemented like this:

```
>>> x = iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> x
<listiterator object at 0x1004ca850>
>>> x.next()
1
>>> x.next()
2
>>> x.next()
3
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

> The built-in function iter takes an iterable object and returns an
>   iterator. Every time we call the method **next()**, the iterator returns the next element. It raises a StopIteration if there are no more elements.

*Source*: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

**zip()** is an iterator and you should turn it into any data structure (list, tuple, set, dict). Each time you call **zip()** (*next()*) it returns a tuple with the pairs you want. So you must append these tuples to a list.

The [**list()** function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) makes exactly that. It takes an iterable (in your case, the iterator function **zip()**), and constructs it as a list.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['p', 'q', 'r']
r = list(zip(a, b))
print(r)

>>> [('a', 'p'), ('b', 'q'), ('c', 'r')]
```

This is the same as:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['p', 'q', 'r']
r = []

for pair in zip(a, b):
    r.append(pair)

print(r)

>>> [('a', 'p'), ('b', 'q'), ('c', 'r')]
```

Or even shorter: `r = [pair for pair in zip(a, b)] # This is a comprehension`

But the best approach is to use **list()**. It is used widely with iterators in Python.

I think this will help you :)